# How to add class to extended block in jade?

Tags: html, preprocessor, pug

I have got two pages. The first one, `parent.jade`, which contains:

```
div.header
    block header
```

And the second one, `child.jade`, contains:

```
extends main
block prepend header
```

So, how I can to add a class for header block in my `child.jade`? I need to have other class naming at the different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you must pass a `object` to jade to be that which is rendering. I.e.

In nodejs

```
jade.renderFile('child.jade', {
    "myIds" : 'FristPage',
    "myClass" : [ 'this', 'is', 'cool' ],
})
```

In your `parent.jade`

```
div.warpper( id=myIds, class=myClass )
    block content
```

When render show

```
<div class="warpper this is cool" id="FristPage">
    The block form child.jade
</div>
```

But it can not do directly from jade or from files jade.